# Dystopic Fiction with massive divide between rich and poor, kids are medicated to not rebel

Tags: story-identification, novel, dystopia

I read a great SF novel about a future city where the divide between rich and poor and education was very stark, even more so than now.

Kids in this high school took meals in pill form, were almost a uniform height and had their intelligence boosted by the pill as well. Their will to rebel or react was stifled somehow by medications.

There was one rebellious teen who managed to turn this system upside down and exposed it, and also a murder I think (with another student who managed to work with him somehow).

There's a scene in the book where a girl is sexually harassed by street toughs and the boys from the high school just freeze and mill around, but this kid that's bucking the system beats the crap out of one of the thugs and they all flee.

This might sound silly, but the hardcover I had had a cover with those wallet-sized pics of people on them. They were all of the same guy that had the same bland facial expression on them with the exception of one that was smiling broadly.

Comment: Any other info you can give us? When did you read this? Where? US or UK or ? Was this part of a series? etc.

Comment: Are the kids on the rich or the poor side of the divide?  "Their will to rebel or react was stifled somehow by medications" sounds poor, but everything else about them sounds rich.

Comment: Well, TVTropes has entries in Literature on [Food Pills](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FoodPills)... Perhaps that might help?

Comment: Some of the kids who were on the poor side of the divide obtained a kind of scholarship that enabled them to attend the schools with the special program in place. It was published in the USA. I originally obtained the book from a Canadian SF book club. I believe the time frame was 2008-12 or thereabouts. It was a stand-alone novel.